# Rails returns invalid JSON when rendering hash containing Float::NAN objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm returning JSON for a Rails controller call. In the controller, I need to generate JSON from a Ruby hash, which contains NaN objects. The browser shows an error when the JSON is returned:

```
{
  "value": NaN
}
```

> Error: Parse error on line 1: "value": NaN

I did some quick research and it seems that NaN is not a valid JSON object, thus should be wrapped in quotes - "NaN". It seems pretty dumb that Rails JSON parser doesn't conform to standard JSON format and wraps the NaN object in quotes.

I've tried to flatten the hash to a string and convert it back to a hash. But I've been consistently getting parse errors.

How do I get around this?

---

EDIT:

To simply the problem, the hash looks like this:

```
{ "value" => Float::NAN }
```

---

EDIT 2:

I need to convert the above hash to the following json:

```
{
  "value": "NaN"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a Ruby hash, which contains NaN objects"? There is nothing called NaN in Ruby. What does the actual hash look like?

Comment: it seems like this was fixed 9 months ago with this https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/7b53d1372df4bbc7a539b5e493ff1491ec460397... I'm using Rails 3.2.3. why am i still seeing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah I figured it out - this was fixed about 10 months ago in the Rails main branch. (https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/7b53d1372df4bbc7a539b5e493ff1491ec460397)

To fix it for your Rails 3.2.3 <, simply add the following code:

```
class Float
  def as_json(options = nil) finite? ? self : NilClass::AS_JSON end #:nodoc:
end
```

Comment: You can find the fix in this file:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb

Comment: This worked for me in Rails 3.2.8 after replacing NilClass::AS_JSON with self.to_s to avoid getting the undefined error mentioned by bprotas.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the sweet [`ActiveModel::Serializer`](https://github.com/josevalim/active_model_serializers#readme) (which are now bundled with rails).  With it you can customize the way the controller serializes your model.

```
class Blark < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :value
end

class BlarkSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :value
  def value
    (@bject.value.is_a?(Float) && @object.value.nan?) ? "NaN" : @object.value
  end
end
```

## Caveat

This only works in the controller's `render` method.  Don't expect it to work in the rails console.  I have [a quick 'n dirty module](http://bit.ly/PevhJ8) that overwrites the methods in `ActiveModel::Serializers` with the ones in `ActiveModel::Serializer` so things are a little more consistent.

Comment: I think you'll find that using `==` against `Float::NAN` won't work. You will have to check that the value is a `Float` and then call `#nan?` on it.

Comment: It works just fine in the console. Just read the docs :P `BlarkSerializer.new(Blark.first).serializable_hash.to_json`

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue, and despite being on Rails 3.2.8, did not find the issue to be fixed per Brian's comment (his suggested code snippet also through an error about NilClass::AS_JSON being undefined).

However, I did find this interesting discussion:

https://github.com/flori/json/pull/145

That seems to indicate that to_json / parse is better for cross-language compatibility, as when communicating over a network, but that JSON.dump / JSON.load provide better results for working only in Ruby.

I found that using dump/load instead of to_json/parse fixed my ability to serialize and deserialize hashes with NaN's in them.

Answer (score 1):

What JSON generator are you using? It seems to be broken.

I get an exception when I try to convert your hash to JSON, using `json` gem v1.6.4:

```
require 'json'

hash = { "value" => Float::NAN }
hash.to_json

# => JSON::GeneratorError: 778: NaN not allowed in JSON
```

If you really need to support serializing NaN values, you will need to replace the Float::NAN values in your hash before converting it to JSON:

```
json_string = hash.inject({}) { |h, (k, v)|
  v = "NaN" if v.is_a?(Float) && v.nan?
  h.merge(k => v)
}.to_json

# => "{\"value\":\"NaN\"}"
```

Don't forget to replace "NaN" strings with Float::NAN again after parsing:

```
hash = JSON.parse(json_string).inject({}) { |h, (k, v)|
  v = Float::NAN if v == "NaN"
  h.merge(k => v)
}
```

Comment: Seriously? Ruby on Rails can't just parse NaN as "NaN"? Why is that?

Answer (score -1):

This hack doesn't require rails and works in vanilla 2.2.x ruby, but be careful to include the 'ensure' block as below.  You can (properly) expect a warning, so use with caution.

```
begin
  tmp = Float::NAN
  Float::NAN = 'NaN'
  { "value" => Float::NAN }.to_json
ensure
  Float::NAN = tmp
end
```